# Working out the time complexity of this code

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o

What is the time complexity for my code with showing your steps? I tried to figure it out by doing O(T+n+n^2+n) = O(T+2n+n^2) = O(n^2). Am I correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T,n, nClone;
    cin >> T;
    while (T--) { //O(T)
        //inputting p[n]
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
        nClone = n;
        int* p = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //O(n)
            scanf_s("%d",&p[i]);
        }

        vector <int>pDash;

        while (n != 0) { //O(n^2)
            //*itr = largest element in the array
            auto itr = find(p, p + n, *max_element(p, p + n));
            for (int i = distance(p, itr); i < n; i++) {
                pDash.push_back(p[i]);
            }
            
            n = distance(p, itr);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nClone; i++) { //O(n)
            printf("%d\n", pDash[i]);
        }
        delete[] p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `O(T * (n + n^2 + n)) == O(T * n^2)`: *nested* loops multiply complexity, so we have `T * n^2`, not `T + n^2`

Comment: In addition to what Dmitry wrote: (1) Since `n` can have a different value in each iteration, it would be more precise to write: O( sum of i=1 to T of: (n_i)^2 ). (2) If I understand the "O(n^2)" loop correctly, I think it is only its worst-case complexity, but its average-case complexity (assuming the content of p is random) is only O(n).

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edit. The shorturl that you provided doesn't lead anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Rules of thumb for complexity arithmetics are

- consequent loops are *added*: `O(loop1) + O(loop2)`
- nested loops are *multiplied*: `O(loop1) * O(loop2)`

In your case:

```
  while (T--) { // O(T)
    ..
    // nested in "while": O(T) * O(n)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // O(n) 
      ...
    }

    // nested in "while": O(T) * O(n)
    while (n != 0) { // O(n) 
      // nested in both "while"s : O(T) * O(n) * O(n)
      for (int i = distance(p, itr); i < n; i++) { // O(n)
        ...
      }
    }

    // nested in "while": O(T) * O(n) 
    for (int i = 0; i < nClone; i++) { // O(n)
      ...
    }
}
```

we have:

```
O(T) * (O(n) + O(n) * O(n) + O(n)) == O(T * n^2)
```